# tf dataset "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'" error on trainning

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.data.dataset, tf.dataset

I try to use tensorflow dataset with a lstm model.
It is my first project integrating tf dataset, so all advices to do it better is welcome.

Here all my fonctions to get data from many csv and process it to dataset:

```
def csv_loader(path):
            return tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset(
                path,
                record_defaults=[tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32], 
                header=header,
                field_delim=',', 
                select_cols=[0,1,2,5],
                na_value='nan')

def split_feature_label(x, lbl_position, nb_attrib):
            output = x[self.input_sequence_length - 1, lbl_position + 1]
            # remove output from input set
            sub = list(range(x.shape[1]))
            sub.pop(lbl_position + 1)  
            # remove id column used by fonction "filter_mixed_csv_sample"
            sub.pop(0)  

            x = tf.transpose(tf.gather(tf.transpose(x), sub))
            return {'input1': x[:self.input_sequence_length, :-nb_attrib],
                    'input2': x[self.input_sequence_length - 1, -nb_attrib:]}, output

def filter_mixed_csv_sample(x):
            # remove samples with mixed csv values 
            y, idx = tf.unique(x[:, 0])
            if len(y) > 1:
                return False
            return True

def filter_nan_missing_values(x):
            # find NaN and reject samples not sure if it always work...
            try:
                ynan = tf.math.is_nan(x)  # return true un ou plusieurs NaN inside sample
                return tf.math.logical_not(tf.math.reduce_any(ynan))  # inverse la réponse pour rejeter avec un False si Nan
            except:
                return False

def to_timeseries(x):
            # turn dataset into 3D lstm compatible dataset
            x = x.map(lambda *items: tf.stack(items), num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
            x = x.window(self.input_sequence_length + self.output_sequence_length, shift=1,
                        drop_remainder=True)  
            x = x.flat_map(lambda i: i).batch(self.input_sequence_length + self.output_sequence_length)
            return x

def is_test(x, _):
        # split dataset into test et trainning dataset
        return x % int(self.val_split * 100) == 0
            
def is_train(x, y):
        return not is_test(x, y)

def apply_scaler(x, y):
            x1_std = (x['input1'] - x1_scaler.data_min_) / (x1_scaler.data_max_ - x1_scaler.data_min_)
            x1_scaled = x1_std * (x1_scaler.feature_range[1] - x1_scaler.feature_range[0]) + x1_scaler.feature_range[0]

            x2_std = (x['input2'] - x2_scaler.data_min_) / (x2_scaler.data_max_ - x2_scaler.data_min_)
            x2_scaled = x2_std * (x2_scaler.feature_range[1] - x2_scaler.feature_range[0]) + x2_scaler.feature_range[0]

            y_std = (y - y_scaler.data_min_) / (y_scaler.data_max_ - y_scaler.data_min_)
            y_scaled = y_std * (y_scaler.feature_range[1] - y_scaler.feature_range[0]) + y_scaler.feature_range[0]
            return {'input1': x1_scaled, 'input2': x2_scaled}, y_scaled
```

and how I order these processing:

```
tf_list = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(list_files, shuffle=True)
dataset = tf_list.interleave(csv_loader, cycle_length=1)

with tf.device('/cpu:0'):  
            dataset = to_timeseries(self.dataset)
            dataset = dataset.ignore_errors()
            dataset = dataset.filter(filter_nan_missing_values)
            dataset = dataset.filter(filter_mixed_csv_sample)
            if shuffle:
                dataset = dataset.shuffle(shuffle_buffer)

            dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: split_feature_label(x, label_index, nb_attributs), num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
            
            # Split dataset to train/test set
            if val_split > 0:
                recover = lambda x, y: y
                test_set = dataset.enumerate() \
                    .filter(is_test) \
                    .map(recover)

                trainning_set = dataset.enumerate() \
                    .filter(is_train) \
                    .map(recover)
            
            # set-up multi-GPUs config if availlable
            if gpu:
                strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
                batch_size_per_replica = batch_size * strategy.num_replicas_in_sync
            else:
                batch_size_per_replica = batch_size
            
            if val_split == 0:
                dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size_per_replica)
                dataset = dataset.cache()
                dataset = dataset.prefetch(2)  
    
            else:
                trainning_set = trainning_set.batch(batch_size_per_replica).cache().prefetch(2)
                test_set = test_set.batch(batch_size_per_replica).cache().prefetch(2)


x1_scaler = load('/artefacts/scalers/x1_scaler.sclr')
x2_scaler = load('/artefacts/scalers/x2_scaler.sclr')
y_scaler = load('/artefacts/scalers/y_scaler.sclr')
dataset = dataset.map(apply_scaler, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

Finnaly, how I start trainning:

```
if val_split > 0:
    history = model.fit(trainning_set, validation_data=test_set,
                        verbose=verbose,
                        epochs=epochs,
                        callbacks=[checkpoint, early_stop],
                        shuffle=shuffle)
            
else:
    history = model.fit(dataset,
                        verbose=verbose,
                        epochs=epochs,
                        callbacks=[checkpoint, early_stop],
                        shuffle=shuffle)
```

These codes was working in an early version, I did some "light" modification like adding multi-GPU optimisation, and re-organized my code to clean not usefull test lines...
now I get this error but realy don't understand what change I did to that and why this error... :

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
unhashable type: 'list'
  File "/home/cy6112/CASTOR-S3/CASTOR-S3-cy6112/Code/timeseries_nn/core.py", line 797, in train
    history = model.fit(dataset,
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/cy6112/CASTOR-S3/CASTOR-S3-cy6112/Code/timeseries_nn/workbench.py", line 33, in <module>
    NN.train(ds, 200, 10, verbose=2, shuffle=True)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

my dataset is:

```
<_ParallelMapDataset element_spec=({'input1': TensorSpec(shape=(None, None, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), 'input2': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 13), dtype=tf.float32, name=None)}, TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.float32, name=None))
```

thank for your help and advice if you see something not did in the good way with dataset

Answer (score 0):

The error you get stems from the `dataset` instance.
In your preprocessing, you are somewhere providing a list as a key to be hashed, but a list is not a hashable type. E.g.,

```
dictionary = {'key': 10}  # This works
dictionary = {['key']: 10}  # This does not
```

I cannot say for sure which value you are erroneously using, but the following line is somewhat suspicious:

```
sub = list(range(x.shape[1]))
```

I suggest you use `breakpoint()` in your functions to check your variables or see where it breaks.

Comment: you probably meen these lines:
            return {'input1': x[:self.input_sequence_length, :-nb_attrib],
                    'input2': x[self.input_sequence_length - 1, -nb_attrib:]}, output  this part don't change and was ok... the code fail on trainning all previous step don't call error... it's why I found nothing. Thank for your help

Answer (score 0):

In my callbacks.ModelCheckpoint I used

```
monitor=['loss', 'val_loss']
```

It is why I get a "list" error...
and I replace it by

```
monitor='loss'
```

or

```
monitor='val_loss'
```

and now it work...

We can't monitor 2 options and use list